# Not a member of the struct/union. I cant seem to find why the error appears

Tags: c

I am struggling to figure out why I am keep getting this error. The purpose of the code / project is taking an analogue value and converting it to digital value which represents a temperature sensor. Also, I have BCD switches but once I show the code it will be clear that it is some small mistake or syntax maybe, but I can't find it.
Any help appreciated.

This is the error message:

```
Error at file ../main.c line 100 column 45: (255) not a member of the struct/union ""
Error at file ../main.c line 100 column 48: (182) illegal conversion between types
int -> volatile union S380
Error at file ../main.c line 101 column 45: (255) not a member of the struct/union ""
Error at file ../main.c line 101 column 48: (182) illegal conversion between types
make: *** [main.p1] Error 1
int -> volatile union S380
```

This is where the error appears.

```
void main(void){
  InitPorts();
  InitADC();

  while(1){
    int SetTemp = Bcd_SW_AB (Read_SwitchB(), Read_SwitchA());
    DispTemp(Rd_ADC());
    if(Rd_ADC() < (SetTemp - 1)){RLED = 1;}
    if(Rd_ADC() > (SetTemp + 1)){RLED = 0;}
  }
}
```

---

```
[Error at file ../main.c line 100 column 45: (255) not a member of the struct/union ""]   
  if(Rd_ADC() < (SetTemp - 1)){RLED = 1;}
    
[ Error at file ../main.c line 101 column 45: (255) not a member of the struct/union ""]   
  if(Rd_ADC() > (SetTemp + 1)){RLED = 0;}
```

This is the complete code:

```
#include <xc.h>

#define RLED LATCbits.LATA0
#define GLED LATCbits.LATA1
//Defining pins on bcd switch A
#define a1 PORTBbits.RB0
#define a2 PORTBbits.RB1
#define a4 PORTBbits.RB2
#define a8 PORTBbits.RB3
//Defining pins on bcd switch B
#define b1 PORTBbits.RB4
#define b2 PORTBbits.RB5
#define b4 PORTBbits.RB6
#define b8 PORTBbits.RB7

void InitPorts(void){
  ANSA0 = 1;        // Set pin to analog
  TRISA0 = 1;       // Set pin to input
  ANSELB = 0;   // Set Port B to digital
  TRISB = 1;        // Set port B to input
  ANSELC = 0 ;  // Set Port C to digital
  TRISC = 0;        // Set Pins to output
  ANSD0 = 0;        //Set pin to digital
  TRISD0 = 0;       //Set pin to output
  ANSD1 = 0;        //Set pin to digital
  TRISD1 = 0;       //Set pin to output
}

void InitADC (void){
  ADCON0bits.CHS = 0; //Channel 0
  ADCON1bits.PVCFG = 0; //+Vref = Vdd
  ADCON1bits.NVCFG = 0; //-Vref = Vss
  ADCON2bits.ADFM = 1; //10-bit operation
  ADCON2bits.ACQT = 0b0000010; //4 Tad
  ADCON2bits.ADCS = 7; //Frc
  ADCON0bits.ADON = 1; //Osc = on 
}

int Rd_ADC(void){
  int Result;
  ADCON0bits.GODONE = 1;
  while (ADCON0bits.GODONE);
  Result =(((ADRESH <<6) | (ADRESL>>2))/2.56);
  return Result;
}

void DispTemp( int BinVal){
  int Bcd[2];
  Bcd[0] = BinVal %10;
  BinVal /= 10;
  Bcd[1] = BinVal % 10;
  BinVal /= 10;
  LATC = Bcd[0];
  LATCbits.LATC4 = 1;
  LATCbits.LATC4 = 0;
  LATC = Bcd[1];
  LATCbits.LATC5 = 1;
  LATCbits.LATC5 = 0;
}

int Read_SwitchA(void){
  int total = 0;
  if (a1) {total+=1;}
  if (a2) {total+=2;}
  if (a4) {total+=4;}
  if (a8) {total+=8;}
  return total;
}

int Read_SwitchB(void){
  int total = 0;
  if (b1) {total+=1;}
  if (b2) {total+=2;}
  if (b4) {total+=4;}
  if (b8) {total+=8;}
  return total*10;
}

int Bcd_SW_AB(int Read_SwitchB, int Read_SwitchA){
  int total = Read_SwitchB + Read_SwitchA;
  return total;
}

void main(void){
  InitPorts();
  InitADC();

  while(1){
    int SetTemp = Bcd_SW_AB (Read_SwitchB(), Read_SwitchA());
    DispTemp(Rd_ADC());
    if(Rd_ADC() < (SetTemp - 1)){RLED = 1;}
    if(Rd_ADC() > (SetTemp + 1)){RLED = 0;}
  }
}
```

Comment: Please mark the lines your compiler errors refer to. I'm not pasting the whole thing into an editor so I can figure out what the compiler told you already.

Comment: it seems obvious that you have something that may be mis-spelled, or mis-referenced in some way that looks like to the compiler that your intent is using a struct member, but it is not included in a struct.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me the content of  `<xc.h>` could be useful, especially the part where they declare `LATCbits`. Please [edit] and show what `LATCbits` is.

Comment: Several objects are referenced that are not declared in the code presented.  Presumably their declarations are provided by `xc.h`, but this is not part of the standard C language.  Most likely, the issue involves one or more of those.

Comment: I did paste the whole thing into an editor, and there are only 93 lines. So those error messages did not come from that code.

Comment: @user3386109 pretty normal you didn't find anything because you don't have `<xc.h>`

Comment: @Jabberwocky perhaps the point is the error is supposed to be on line 100, but there aren't that many lines in what I copy/pasted either.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: I edited my question, I showed now what error message I get on that line of code beneath it.

Comment: You have not shown the `struct` definition, but in another place you have `LATCbits.LATC4` etc. so perhaps `LATCbits.LATA0` in the macro is a typo.

Comment: And _please_ indent your code properly...

Comment: So my first guess was right, something is wrong with `LATCbits`. Show the declaration of `LATCbits` from `<xc.h>`. BTW: no need for greatings, like "Good day", "hello", "thank" you etc. This site is only about questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to this macro definition ...

> ```
> #define RLED LATCbits.LATA0
> ```

, this error ...

> Error at file ../main.c line 100 column 45: (255) not a member of the struct/union ""

... referencing this line of code ...

> ```
>     if(Rd_ADC() < (SetTemp - 1)){RLED = 1;}
> ```

... seems to be saying that the type of `LATCbits` is an untagged structure or union type that does not have any member named `LATA0`.

It is plausible that the "illegal conversion" errors just cascade from the "not a member" error, such that they do not indicate a separate issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, I found the mistake. Thanks, @ryyker for letting me know I should recheck my spelling, and thanks to @jabberwocky for putting my focus on LATCbits where to mistype was.

So LATCbits is a register on the pic microcontroller and I initially defined the LEDs to be on LATC and later changed it for them to be on LATD and never changed my code.

This was the part that had to change:

form this(wrong) :

```
#define RLED LATCbits.LATA0
#define GLED LATCbits.LATA1
```

to this(correct):

```
#define RLED LATDbits.LATD0
#define GLED LATDbits.LATD1
```

for anyone you wants to see the correct code:

```
#include <xc.h>

#define RLED LATDbits.LATD0
#define GLED LATDbits.LATD1
//Defining pins on bcd switch A
#define a1 PORTBbits.RB0
#define a2 PORTBbits.RB1
#define a4 PORTBbits.RB2
#define a8 PORTBbits.RB3
//Defining pins on bcd switch B
#define b1 PORTBbits.RB4
#define b2 PORTBbits.RB5
#define b4 PORTBbits.RB6
#define b8 PORTBbits.RB7

void InitPorts(void){
ANSA0 = 1;      // Set pin to analog
TRISA0 = 1;     // Set pin to input
ANSELB = 0; // Set Port B to digital
TRISB = 1;      // Set port B to input
ANSELC = 0 ;    // Set Port C to digital
TRISC = 0;      // Set Pins to output
ANSD0 = 0;      //Set pin to digital
TRISD0 = 0;     //Set pin to output
ANSD1 = 0;      //Set pin to digital
TRISD1 = 0;     //Set pin to output
}

void InitADC (void){
 ADCON0bits.CHS = 0; //Channel 0
 ADCON1bits.PVCFG = 0; //+Vref = Vdd
 ADCON1bits.NVCFG = 0; //-Vref = Vss
 ADCON2bits.ADFM = 1; //10-bit operation
 ADCON2bits.ACQT = 0b0000010; //4 Tad
 ADCON2bits.ADCS = 7; //Frc
 ADCON0bits.ADON = 1; //Osc = on 
}

int Rd_ADC(void){
int Result;
ADCON0bits.GODONE = 1;
while (ADCON0bits.GODONE);
Result =(((ADRESH <<6) | (ADRESL>>2))/2.56);
return Result;
}

void DispTemp( int BinVal){
int Bcd[2];
Bcd[0] = BinVal %10;
BinVal /= 10;
Bcd[1] = BinVal % 10;
BinVal /= 10;
LATC = Bcd[0];
LATCbits.LATC4 = 1;
LATCbits.LATC4 = 0;
LATC = Bcd[1];
LATCbits.LATC5 = 1;
LATCbits.LATC5 = 0;
}

int Read_SwitchA(void){
int total = 0;
if (a1) {total+=1;}
if (a2) {total+=2;}
if (a4) {total+=4;}
if (a8) {total+=8;}
return total;
}
int Read_SwitchB(void){
int total = 0;
if (b1) {total+=1;}
if (b2) {total+=2;}
if (b4) {total+=4;}
if (b8) {total+=8;}
return total*10;
}

int Bcd_SW_AB(int Read_SwitchB, int Read_SwitchA){
int total = Read_SwitchB + Read_SwitchA;
return total;
}

void main(void){
InitPorts();
InitADC();

while(1){
    int SetTemp = Bcd_SW_AB (Read_SwitchB(), Read_SwitchA());
    DispTemp(Rd_ADC());
    if(Rd_ADC() < (SetTemp - 1)){RLED = 1;}
    if(Rd_ADC() > (SetTemp + 1)){RLED = 0;}
 }
}
```